# Django OpenID Connect and OAuth2.0 - Splitting Authorization Server and Resource Server

Tags: python, django, oauth, oauth-2.0, openid

I have multiple Resource Servers and one Auth Server all written in Django. I have implemented OIDC Provider in the Auth Server using [Django OIDC Provider Library](https://django-oidc-provider.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). So it provides OAuth 2.0 support as well.

Having [OAuth 2.0 Token Introspection (RFC 7662)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7662) implemented, it allows authorized protected resources to query the authorization server to determine the set of metadata(and verification) for a given access token that was presented to them by an OAuth 2.0 client.

I'm getting trouble in setting up the Resource Server, as there's no `RESOURCE_SERVER_INTROSPECTION_URL` provided like other standard OAuth 2.0 providers for internally verifying the access token with Auth Server(using an internal post request to Auth Server).

For example in the [Django OAuth Toolkit](https://django-oauth-toolkit.readthedocs.io/) library, it has clearly been specified in their [documentation](https://django-oauth-toolkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/resource_server.html#setup-the-resource-server).

But In Django OIDC Provider, they have provided a hook for that [`OIDC_INTROSPECTION_PROCESSING_HOOK`](https://django-oidc-provider.readthedocs.io/en/latest/sections/settings.html#oidc-introspection-processing-hook), which I could not understand how to use. Also, there's no detail about it on [their official page](https://django-oidc-provider.readthedocs.io/en/latest/sections/tokenintrospection.html).

I need help in setting up my separate resource servers which can rely on my Auth Server for any token creation and verification.

I want to set up an introspect endpoint something like this in my resource server `settings.py` file:

```
OAUTH_PROVIDER = {
    ...
    'RESOURCE_SERVER_INTROSPECTION_URL': 'https://example.org/o/introspect/',
    'RESOURCE_SERVER_AUTH_TOKEN': '<Interospection Token>', 
    ...
}
```

or small customization in their provided default hook will also be helpful. And how to configure it to communicate with my Auth Server.

```
def default_introspection_processing_hook(introspection_response, client, id_token):

    # Verification Logic Here 
    return introspection_response
```

Any help will be much appreciated.